# Different timing samples' analysis

Tags: multivariate-analysis

How can I put my data in a sheet if I have a number of patients and each patient have different number of samples with different timing? How can I analyse data grouping data samples for each different patient?

Answer (score 2):

You can store your data using the so-called "long data format".

In other words, in your data spreadsheet, define four columns:

```
PatientID   SampleNumber  SampleDate  SampleValue
```

Then record the data available for each patient along these lines:

```
PatientID   SampleNumber    SampleDate     SampleValue 
     1           1        Jan 1, 2019          20.5
     1           2        Jan 2, 2019          19.3
     2           1        Jan 3, 2019          21.2
     2           2        Jan 4, 2019          17.8
     2           3        Jan 5, 2019          18.5
     Etc.
```

How you analyze your data will ultimately depend on what questions you want to be able to answer on the basis of these data. You will need to provide more specifics to that end.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'll try to explain my data. I've got a number of patients with the same diagnosis but different clinical features (eg karyotype, chronological age, bone age etc). They all perform the same analysis with different timing (at different ages) and under different therapies. I'd like to know how to group them by the ID to make a descriptive analysis of my group of patients and how to analyse their samples making a correlation both withe the age and with the therapy at each time of the evaluation.  I hope you could understand and thank you for your help.